# How to access struct fields in assembly x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct item {
    int low; int high; char label[16];
} Item;

typedef struct item_coll {
    size_t length; Item *items[];
} ItemColl;

extern int find_first_in_range(ItemColl *ic, int rlow, int rhigh);

/*
char *find_first_in_range(ItemColl *ic, int rlow, int rhigh) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ic->length; i++)
        if (ic->items[i]->low >= rlow && ic->items[i]->high <= rhigh)
            return &ic->items[i]->label[0];
    return NULL;
}
* */

int main() {

    struct item fruits[] = {
        {10, 20, "Apple"},
        {12, 14, "Pear"},
        { 8, 12, "Banana"},
        { 2,  4, "Grape"},
        {15, 35, "Watermelon"}
    };

    struct item_coll *basket = malloc (sizeof *basket + 5 * sizeof *basket->items);
    basket->length = 5;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
        basket->items[i] = &fruits[i];

    int label = find_first_in_range (basket, 12, 15);
    printf ("%d\n", label);

    free (basket);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I access the different fields in `fruits`?
Right now I was able to come up with the following information:

```
xor %r12, %r12
add $8, %r12
mov (%rdi, %r12), %rdi
mov (%rdi), %rax
ret
```

- This will give me the `10` from `Apple`.
- If I don't use `%r12` and just load `%rdi`'s value from memory, I get `5` (the `basket`'s length).
- If I add `16` to `%r12`, I get the `12` from `Pear`.
- If I add `24` to `%r12` I get the `8` from `Banana`.

How do I access for example the `20` in `Apple`? Shouldn't I just need to add `12` to `%r12`? It's giving me segmentation fault.

Comment: To get the `20` you need to offset the **second** memory access, that is change `mov (%rdi), %rax` to `mov 4(%rdi), %eax`. Note that `int` is 4 bytes.

Comment: Why am I being able to get the `12` and the `8` without doing that?

Comment: The second memory access is for the field in a single item. Since the `12` and the `8` are the first field they have offset zero. The `20` is the second field and has offset `4`.

Comment: How could you figure all that out? I don't know how the memory is supposed to be mapped when I look at the structure.

Comment: I'm trying to get to the `Apple` string now and I can't see it. I'm trying to add `$12` instead of `$8` on `%r12`. I'm trying to change the return type to `* char` and to print the string.

Comment: @Jester: I tried doing `mov 8(%rdi), %rax` and keeping the `add $8, %r12` and it still doesn't give me the string.

Comment: That should give you the string, maybe you are printing it wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185937/discussion-between-vegas-and-jester).

Comment: You should try compiling your C function and looking at the resulting asm.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  e.g. like this: https://godbolt.org/z/NrT2LF.  And BTW, your code would probably be more efficient if `ItemColl` just had a pointer to an array of `Item` objects, instead of your current array of pointers where it takes two dereferences to get to the fields of each `Item` .  To sort collections according to a key or something, then sure copying around 8-byte pointers instead of 32-byte objects is ok, esp. without AVX.